# Abrir sub directorias com explorer em C#

Tags: c#

Estou a fazer uma aplicação cuja finalidade é pesquisar e abrir uma sub directoria dentro de uma pasta que se encontra num servidor. Mas o que consigo fazer até ao momento é apenas pesquisar e abrir as pastas que estão na raiz...

O meu código está assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
         public Form1()
         {
                 InitializeComponent();
         }
         private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
         }
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
                 string filepath = string.Format("C:\\TESTE\\{0}", textBox1.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                 System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                 prc.StartInfo.FileName = filepath;
                 prc.Start();
         }

}
}
```

Sei que tenho de utilizar uma função recursiva para percorrer todas as pastas mas não estou a conseguir encaixar a função naquilo que pretendo ou seja: o utilizador insere na textbox a pasta a procurar, carrega no botão pesquisar e abrir e se existir abre com o explorer essa pasta:

```
public void GetSubDirectories()
{
string root = @"C:\teste";

string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(root);

foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
         LoadSubDirs(subdirectory);
}
private void LoadSubDirs(string dir)
{
Console.WriteLine(dir);
string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
{
         LoadSubDirs(subdirectory);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para percorrer todas os subdiretórios de forma recursiva utilize o seguinte método:

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir)
   {
       try
       {
           foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
           {
               foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(f);
               }
               DirSearch(d);
           }
       }
       catch (System.Exception excpt)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
       }
   }
```

Referência: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Se necessita de encontrar todos os diretórios e os seus filhos pode usar o método [Directory.GetDirectories(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms143314%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string pastaInicial = "C:\teste";
string pastaAEncontrar = "aMinhaPasta";
string[] listaDePastas = Directory.GetDirectories(pastaInicial, pastaAEncontrar, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
// pode verificar se há uma só pasta, se há varias pastas, se não há pastas
```

A opção `SearchOption.AllDirectories` faz com que `GetDirectories(...)` procure a pasta a encontrar na pasta inicial e nos seus descendentes.

Comment: Alguem quer explicar o porque do -1?

Comment: Pois é, tenho visto muito isso, o pessoal negativa a questão e quer que o cara use de poderes psionicos para entender a subjetividade do rabo da lagartixa. Suponho que é porque você não responde a parte de encaixar o metodo e depois abrir com o Explorer.